# Populating table in django using jquery ajax

Tags: python, jquery, html, ajax, django

My problem - I am trying to make a table which will take the data from my django code through the database. i have managed to get the data from my database to the ajax call in the form of a queryset. i need to now get the data into the table. Below is my code -

this is my jquery ajax code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ReusableId').on('change',function(){
    var catid;
    catid = $(this).find(':selected').attr("data-catid");
    alert(catid);
        $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: "InputColumns",
                    data:{catid:catid},
                    success: function (data) {
                    alert (data);
                    $('#inputc').append("<td> he" + data['id'] + "</td>");
                    $('#outputc').append("<td> he" + data['id'] + "</td>")
             ;},
        });
        })
        });
```

this is my views.py code -

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def get_columns(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        cat_id= request.GET['catid']
        inputc=Input.objects.filter(iref_id=catid)        
        inputl=list(inputc)
        return HttpResponse({inputc:inputc})
```

This is my html code -

```
<html>
<body>
<table id="table" class="table">
<thead>
<th>Input Name</th>
<th>Is Req</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<td name = "#inputc" id = "#inputc">
{%for input in inputc%}
{{inputc}}                                                                              
{%endfor%}                                                                           
</td>
<td name = "#inputc" id = "#inputc">
{%for input in inputc%}
{{inputc}}                                                                              
{%endfor%}                                                                           
</td>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

My data which is being inputed is like this -

```
<QuerySet [<Input: Input object (1)>, <Input: Input object (2)>, <Input: Input object (3)>]>
```

Im unable to display this.

Comment: This looks solid to me, what error(s) are you getting ?

Comment: No errors..the data isnt populating in the html...

Comment: looks like you wanted to use "inputl" while passing it in context. You are using "inputc"